# VB: Fill multiple textboxes with data from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So, I have this program which has to store a lot of different info from users and shows it through Textboxes, Numerics, etc when the Form loads. At first I thought it would be easy, but as soon as I started writing the code I figured that if I would do the easy way (the way I know) I would have to write hundreds of Subs, each one with a MySQL query and then assign, one by one, the values to their respective textboxes, comboboxes, etc.

So, how can I pull data from multiple rows from a MySQL DB and then assign the data from each one of those rows to textboxes?

This is what I have now, which works fine, but only for getting one single value from the DB:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class GetInfo


    Public Shared Sub Run()

        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim result As String

        Dim Query_Read As String = "Select Nome FROM dk_db_sql_yog." & Username
        Dim Cmd_Read_Name As New MySqlCommand(Query_Read)
        Cmd_Read_Name.Connection = Connect
        reader = Cmd_Read_Name.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.Read() Then
            If reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                result = ""
            Else
                result = reader.GetString(0)
            End If
        End If

        Form1.Name_Textbox.Text = result
        reader.Close()

     End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Could you show a few more iterations? And how many TextBoxes are there? Hundreds???

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Well there are probably something like ~150 boxes to be filled. And sorry, I didn't understand what you asked me to show more (not native english here :x)

Comment: Do you want to loop through a collection of users? Something like `For each user in myTableOfUsers` What is the name of the next two TextBox controls?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå No. The Form will open and then Run that Sub I posted. That Sub only search trough a table specified by the user (the '& username' part in the code). That table contains all the user's info (like Name, Age, resources and etc). Then I need to get the data from each row in that table and then assign them to the program's textboxes.

Comment: I've added an answer. But i strongly suggest that you consider merging all tables into one `users` table. In my opinion, and I might be wrong, this is bad database structuring.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå you are correct. There should only be one users table

Comment: @AndreSilva Then you could use a [MySqlDataAdapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html) to select one row (a user), fill to a DataTable, and iterate over columns. `For Each c As DataColumn In myResultTable.Columns`. Inside that loop do `Form1.Controls.Item(String.Concat(c.ColumnName, "_Textbox")).Text = myResultTable.Rows(0).Item(c).ToString()`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Ok, I'll try changing it later. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you may use a datatable:

```
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
Dim result As New Datatable

Dim Query_Read As String = "Select Nome, Nome1, Nome2 FROM dk_db_sql_yog." & Username
Dim Cmd_Read_Name As New MySqlCommand(Query_Read)
Cmd_Read_Name.Connection = Connect
result.Load(Cmd_Read_Name.ExecuteReader)

With Form1
  For Each dtrow AS DataRow in result.rows
     .Name_Textbox1.Text = dtrow(0)
     .Name_Textbox2.Text = dtrow(1)
     .Name_Textbox3.Text = dtrow(2)
  Next
End With
```

Comment: It says that Value of type MySqlDataReader cannot be converted to a Datatable in `result = Cmd_Read_Name.ExecuteReader`

Comment: @AndreSilva Correct, you can not. `ExecuteReader` returns a reader, not a datatable, thus the error.

Comment: you just need to change `result = Cmd_Read_Name.ExecuteReader` to `result.Load(Cmd_Read_Name.ExecuteReader)` and then you can loop through the DataTable

Comment: @Jeff Oh that worked! Thanks! I only had to change `result As Datatable` to `result As New Datatable` so it wouldn't result in an exception.